# Saddle-point method for complex functional of real field

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-manifolds

If I have a path integral of the form

$$\int D\phi e^{i S}$$

where the action S is a complex functional of a real-valued field $\phi$, say

$$S=\int dt ( \phi^2 + i \phi )$$

what is the correct way to perform a saddle-point approximation? Should I minimize the real part of S, the imaginary part, or just make the whole S stationary?

Answer (score 1):

The imaginary part of $S$ modifies the measure of the integration over $\phi$, it plays no role in the saddle-point approximation, which involves only the real part of $S$. (Recall that this is the method of ["stationary *phase*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation) and the "phase" of the exponential $e^{iS}$ refers to the real part of $S$.) You do want to make sure the imaginary part of $S$ still allows for a convergent integral.